# Clicking on the entire row of Android ListView

Tags: android

I have Created a ListView and set a background image.Everything goes fine except I am unable to click on the right side of the row of ListView.Can anybody help me this.
Below is the xml file...

```
    <ListView 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:id="@+id/JSONListView"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:background="@drawable/listbg"
       android:focusable="false" 
       android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
       android:visibility="visible" >
    </ListView>
```

And I am not using any View.

Comment: You should have another XML layout for your rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the attribute

```
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

and set click listener for items.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have created your custom adapter. If so, just go to the `getView()` method of that custom adapter and on the holder instance of that portion of listitem add a onCLickListener.

Comment: That solved the issue for me, but I truly believe that this is not the way it should be done. An adapter is absolutely not responsible for passing a click event to the containing view, that's the task of the ListView itself. Anyhow, thanks for the idea. +1

Answer (score 0):

Provide more info. XML layout, etc.

Im guessing there is a view there or it is not filling the entire width but difficult to say.

[Android ListView Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: Please check the XML layout I have modified the question

Comment: You still need more info. You must be assigning a layout in the Activity which each row uses... You are either using something standard or overriding with a custom row view which allows for custom buttons relevant to each row for that row. have you checked the android documentation?